# Determine byte Length of a String in AL32UTF8, when NLS_CHARACTERSET is not set to AL32UTF8

Tags: sql, oracle, string-length

We are sending some data from development to client. Our dev instances don't use AL32UTF8 as NLS_CHARSET. But client uses it. 
So we need to truncate data before we send it to client. But truncation should happen in terms of AL32UTF8 byte length.

How to determine length of string according to AL32UTF8 when my current db setting don't have NLS_CHARSET = AL32UTF8

lengthb('A String')

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense - why do you have to truncate data, meaning what your client gets isn't what you hold anyway (as you'll lose some of it)? How are you sending/transferring the data? And what is your database character set?

Comment: We are not truncating the data at our db. Before pushing the data into client environment using client APIs (Interlinked servers) we gotta truncate the data and send it. I've seen a comment which seems to be trust worthy. `SELECT LENGTHB(CONVERT('ABC','AL32UTF8')) len from dual;`

Comment: Note that Oracle discourages the use of `CONVERT` except in specific use cases - and recommends not using it as a part of application logic.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620

Comment: Make sure you understand what that's actually doing and for, and the [note about Oracle discouraging its use](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CONVERT.html#GUID-C8BA0657-61C8-4964-A4CB-9292390853F6). I still don't understand your issue though. If 'interlinked servers' means database links, then conversion should be automatic and transparent?